# C# smtp stopped working but works on another computer

Tags: c#, email

My c# program is sending an email and it has suddenly started to receive the following error

> The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

On another computer, I run the same code using visual studio 2013 (in both computers), within the same domain, logged in as the same user and it works fine.  The email has been working fine for the last 3 days but suddenly stopped working. I did the obvious, reboot, etc. The email admin says nothing is wrong or changed. Anyone have any clues? The code is below

```
        MailMessage errorEmail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("relay.xxxx.com");
        errorEmail.From = new MailAddress("ARExportProgram@xxx.com");
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        foreach (var address in Properties.Settings.Default.monitorEmails.
                Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            errorEmail.To.Add(address);
        }
        errorEmail.Subject = "ARExport Program Error";
        errorEmail.Body = "my message";

        SmtpServer.Send(errorEmail);
```

Comment: My guess is that the problem isn't with this code specifically, but the context that it runs in.  Something has changed somewhere.  You're sending anonymously - have you tried attaching credentials?

Comment: Don't believe the admin.  Usually on Corporate Networks UseDefaultCredentials = false won't work.  You need to go through a proxy server that won't recognize a credential that is not stored on the PC.  With credentials true the username and password stored locally on the PC as part of the Outlook setup will work.

Comment: I did try adding the credentials and it did not work. This morning everything worked again so I think the "don't believe the Admin" is good advice.  Thanks for the repsonses.